# How to create an object inside an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a want to create a object Metrics within which I need to initialize various other objects such as StatsD.

I know how to create Metrics object in javascript.

```
function Metrics(params) {
  // initialize params
}

Metrics.prototype.functionName = function() {

}
```

However I am confused is how to embed an object inside another object and access its methods ?

In java it would be easy:

```
class Metrics {
   StatsD statsD;
}

new Metrics().statsD.increment("foobar");
```

How would I do the same in javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it in the same way as in Java:

```
function Metrics(params) {
    this.statsd = new StatssD();
}
```

The only difference is that you don't have to declare the attribute with its type - just initialising the property in the constructor is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property (`statsd` in this case) to a new object (`new StatsD()`):

```
function Metrics(params) {
    //Initialize params
    this.statsd = new StatsD();
}
```

You could also attach the `StatsD` to the `prototype`:

```
Metrics.prototype.statsd = StatsD();
```